# Publish python package into private repository behind VPN

Tags: python, aws-vpc, artifactory, github-actions, vpn

I'm using Github Actions to publish my python packages automatically. When working with PyPI everything works fine and providing different config to point on different repository is not an issue.
But when repository (JFrong artifactory) is located behind VPN GH Actions is not able to push/fetch from there.

What is the right approach to deal with such kind of situation? Is there any kind of existing solution for this issue?

Comment: The difficulty with this action is that VPN requires certificates to establish the connection and creates a new network dynamically which then gives you access to the subnetwork by routing your request. Now GH actions run in a container bases serverless environment behind a peripherical firewall so most likely you will not be able to change the network configurations because it needs ` root ` access.

Comment: @BodoHugoBarwich is it possible to spawn some kind of a tunnel withing the agent/container?

Comment: my strategy would be to create a source code release zip file and publish it on GitHub and then download it from within the VPN to push it to the intern repository. https://github.com/marketplace/actions/create-github-release

Answer (score 0):

So I found similar question (regarding installing, but works for publishing as well) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73624685/install-python-package-from-private-artifactory-behind-vpn

Basically, you can either setup GH Actions runner within VPN or use proxy to access your resorces.

I have ended up using answer from comments

> my strategy would be to create a source code release zip file and publish it on GitHub and then download it from within the VPN to push it to the intern repository. github.com/marketplace/actions/create-github-release

and still run separate job for publishing into internal repository.